# Algebraic expression in its most simplified form

Tags: algebra-precalculus, factoring, rational-functions

I am trying to simplify the algebraic expression:

$$\bigg(x-\dfrac{4}{(x-3)}\bigg)\div \bigg(x+\dfrac{2+6x}{(x-3)}\bigg)$$

I am having trouble though. My current thoughts are:

$$=\bigg(\dfrac{x}{1}-\dfrac{4}{(x-3)}\bigg)\div \bigg(\dfrac{x}{1}+\dfrac{2+6x}{(x-3)}\bigg)$$

$$=\bigg(\dfrac{x(x-3)}{1(x-3)}-\dfrac{4}{(x-3)}\bigg)\div \bigg(\dfrac{x(x-3)}{1(x-3)}+\dfrac{2+6x}{(x-3)}\bigg)$$

$$=\bigg(\dfrac{x(x-3)+(-4)}{(x-3)}\bigg)\div \bigg(\dfrac{x(x-3)+2+6x}{(x-3)}\bigg)$$

$$=\dfrac{x(x-3)+(-4)}{(x-3)}\times \dfrac{(x-3)}{x(x-3)+2+6x}$$

$$=\dfrac{x(x-3)+(-4)(x-3)}{(x-3)x(x-3)+2+6x} $$

$$\boxed{=\dfrac{-4(x-3)}{2(1+3x)} }$$ Which does not appear is not the answer. Am I close? Where exactly did I go wrong? I have tried this question multiple times.

**Edit: Figured it out!**

$\dfrac{x(x-3) - 4}{x(x - 3) + 2(1 + 3x)}\implies\dfrac{x^2-3x-4}{x^2+3x+2}\implies \dfrac{(x-4)(x+1)}{(x+2)(x+1)}$

$(x+1)$'s cancel leaving us with: $\boxed{\dfrac{x-4}{x+2}}$

Comment: Good work on the update! :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You did not distribute the term $(x - 3)$ in the denominator when you wrote:

$$\begin{align} & =\dfrac{x(x-3)+(-4)}{(x-3)}\times \dfrac{(x-3)}{x(x-3)+2+6x} \\ \\ & =\dfrac{x(x-3)+(-4)(x-3)}{(x-3)x(x-3)+2+6x} \end{align}$$

What would be correct is the following denominator:
$$\begin{align} & \quad\color{blue}{(x-3)}[x(x-3)+2+6x] \\ \\ & = \color{blue}{(x-3)}x(x-3)+\color{blue}{(x-3)}(2+6x)\end{align} $$

---

But note

$$\dfrac{x(x-3)+(-4)}{\color{blue}{\bf (x-3)}}\times \dfrac{\color{blue}{\bf(x-3)}}{x(x-3)+2+6x}$$

The highlighted terms cancel, leaving you:

$$\begin{align} & =\dfrac{x(x-3)+(-4)}{1}\times \dfrac{1}{x(x-3)+2+6x} \\ \\
& = \frac{x(x-3) - 4}{x(x - 3) + 2 + 6x} \\ \\
& = \dfrac{x^2-3x-4}{x^2+3x+2} \tag{$\diamondsuit$}
\end{align} $$

Now, all both the numerator and denominator of $\diamondsuit$ factor very nicely, and in fact, share a common factor, and hence, can be further simplified.

---

Recall: $$\frac{[b + c]a}{a[d+e]} = \frac{a[b+c]}{a[d+e]} = \frac{b+c}{d+e}$$

Or: $$\frac{a[b+c]}{a[d+e]} = \frac{ab+ac}{ad+ae}= \frac{b+c}{d+e}$$

Comment: Okay, but once at: $\frac{x(x-3) - 4}{x(x - 3) + 2(1 + 3x)}$ The (x-3)'s cancel Leaving the Numerator as x-4 but the denominator still has x+2(1+3x). What else am I missing here?

Comment: Got it. Redistributing and factoring again I get trinomials which simplify further $\dfrac{x^2-3x-4}{x^2+3x+2}\implies \dfrac{(x-1)(x+1)}{(x+2)(x+1)}$ (x+1)'s cancel leaving us with: $\dfrac{x-4}{x+2}$. Thanks alot amWhy!

Comment: @Amzoti Thanks!

Comment: @nitrous2 You're welcome!

Answer (score 1):

Comment: After the calculation very well described by AWertheim and amWhy, we end up wit $\dfrac{x^2-3x-4}{x^2+3x+2}$.

Note that the calculation is *not* over. The top and bottom each factor nicely, and there will be some cancellation.